# CRM Dynamics 2011 Custom Workflow Activity

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, workflow-activity

I have an issue with my CRM Workflow which I wrote a workflow activity for and added it as a step in my CRM workflow. The custom workflow references a WCF service which queries data using EF.

I understand well about configuring my endpoint bindings in code and all. All is well until I deploy the workflow and try to run in from CRM. I get the following error

> Type 'Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InprocessServiceProxy' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

It seems to not be able to serialize the objects properly. I have looked everywhere on the web but no luck at all.

Comment: my actual service doesn't have any properties to serialize. I am failing to serialize CRM Input Parameters.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to send data through WCF you need to make your attributes serializables, something like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace = "Some.Name.Space")]
public class ClassResponse
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sxntk, my actual service doesnt have any properties to serialize. I am failing to serialize CRM Input Parameters. Please see below                              [DataMember]
[Input("Brand")]
[AttributeTarget("tcn_brand", "tcn_brandid")]
public InArgument<EntityReference> Brand { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[Input("Directory Path")]
public InArgument<string> DirectoryPath { get; set; }
        
 [DataMember]
[Input("File Name")]
public InArgument<string> FileName { get; set; }

Comment: Write your code or at least, the part when you call the service.